# why does SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() return null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

in what case does `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` return null?

i am doing this:

```
Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", , adCmdText)
capture_id = rs.Fields(0)
```

and i getting `capture_id=null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), "The SCOPE_IDENTITY() function will return the null value if the function is invoked before any INSERT statements into an identity column occur in the scope."

Comment: ok so you aren't saying what the solution is...how to keep it IN scope.  I have the same problem, I've got an insert attempt into a temp table variable and check for the identity the line right after the end of the insert statement and it's null.  So how the hell do you keep it in scope with the insert?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier, but since I'm here I figured I might as well respond for posterity :)  You need the SCOPE_IDENTITY() call to be in the same batch as the INSERT statement.  Either put all the code into a stored procedure and call the proc, or put all the statements into a single ad-hoc batch and do a single execute.

Answer (score 8):

To be more specific, SCOPE_IDENTITY() only returns the latest identity value generated within the same scope as the SCOPE_IDENTITY() call.  In the example you posted, the SCOPE_IDENTITY() call is the only statement in the batch (hence the only statement within the current scope) so it will return null.  If you want to get the latest identity value generated for a particular table, try IDENT_CURRENT('tablename').  This is not subject to scope, it just gives you the latest identity value generated for the given table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Identity Specification is set to yes:

[image]